# C - "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'str' was corrupted."

Tags: c, arrays

I debugged, I searched for an answer online, but I couldn't find something 
    that should help me.
    the problem is in the function op3, for some reason it saying that the str str corrupted, but I don't understand why there isn't an overflow. 
    I wasted hours...but still no luck...please help me to understand why.
    thank you.

```
#define N 4

char op3(char mat[N][N]);

void main()
{
    char mat1[N][N];
    op3(mat1);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%c", mat1[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    system("pause");
}


char op3(char mat[N][N])
{
    char str[N], ch;
    int count = N - 1;
    printf("Enter a string with %d length: ", N);
    scanf("%s", &str);
    while (strlen(str) != N)
    {
        printf("Error: Enter a string with %d length: ", N);
        scanf("%s", str);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            mat[i][j] = str[j];
        ch = str[count];
        for (int k = 0; k < N - 1; k++)
        {
            str[count] = str[count - 1];
            count--;
        }
        count = N - 1;
        str[0] = ch;
    }
}
```

Comment: note : `char str[N]` ... `strlen(str) != N` : `strlen(str) == N` is impossible as normal operation.

Comment: Firstly, `main` returns `int`. You are checking for 4 inputs whereas strings are always terminated with `NULL` character.

Comment: What input did you provide? What do you expect to happen if the string is longer than `N`?

Comment: You got a compile warning about this code, don't ignore it.  Use `scanf_s` as the warning said, it forces you to get this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in C are null terminated.  So a string of length N requires a buffer of size N+1 to store it.

When you `scanf("%s", str)`, you will write N+1 characters into the array, which can potentially corrupt your stack.

```
char str[N+1]
```

or `scanf("%4c", str)` should work, though the former is susceptible to buffer overflows.

should fix it.